# bash: asmca: command not found... oracle database

Tags: linux, oracle

I couldn't get oracle's asmca to work. it says command not found.
I can execute sqlplus and rman but asmca is not working.
My bash_profile looks like this.

```
# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH

export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export GRID_HOME=/u01/app/19c/grid
export DB_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/19c/db_1
export ORACLE_HOME=$DB_HOME
export ORACLE_SID=racdb1
export ORACLE_TERM=xterm
export BASE_PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$BASE_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/JRE:$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib

alias grid='./home/oracle/grid.env'
alias db='./home/oracle/db.env'
```

Comment: You have added `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` to your PATH, but `asmca` is under `$GRID_HOME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your current $PATH to `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:/u01/app/19c/grid/bin:$DB_HOME/bin`